# Possible arrangements of the word ARRANGEMENT

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

In how many the alphabets of the word **ARRANGEMENT** can be arranged such that :

- **Exactly** two pairs of consecutive identical alphabets appear in the arrangement?
- **At least** two pairs of consecutive identical alphabets appear in the arrangement?

---

What I've tried so far:

The alphabets that can be repeated should appear more than once in the given word, these are $$\text{AA,EE,NN,RR}$$

The answer to the first part is given by :
$$\binom{4}{2}\left[\frac{9!}{\left(2!\right)^{2}}-\binom{2}{1}\frac{8!}{\left(2!\right)^{1}}+\binom{2}{2}\frac{7!}{\left(2!\right)^{0}}\right]$$

For the second question it's needed to subtract the cases where less than two pair of consecutive alphabets appear in the arrangement from the total arrangements of the given word:

$$\frac{11!}{\left(2!\right)^{4}}$$
$$-\left[\underbrace{\frac{11!}{\left(2!\right)^{4}}-\binom{4}{1}\frac{10!}{\left(2!\right)^{3}}+\binom{4}{2}\frac{9!}{\left(2!\right)^{2}}-\binom{4}{3}\frac{8!}{\left(2!\right)^{1}}+\binom{4}{4}\frac{7!}{\left(2!\right)^{0}}}_{\text{Arrangements with no pair of consecutive identical alphabets}}\right]$$
$$-\binom{4}{1}\left[\underbrace{\frac{10!}{\left(2!\right)^{3}}-\binom{3}{1}\frac{9!}{\left(2!\right)^{2}}+\binom{3}{2}\frac{8!}{\left(2!\right)^{1}}-\binom{3}{3}\frac{7!}{\left(2!\right)^{0}}}_{\text{Arrangements with only one pair of consecutive identical alphabets}}\right]$$
$$=\color{green}{398160}$$

But the other way I came with was to compute the number of arrangements with two pairs of consecutive identical alphabets which is given by $$\binom{4}{2}\frac{9!}{\left(2!\right)^{2}}$$

I thought that these are the arrangements that at least two such pairs will appear but I don't understand why this way gives the wrong answer?

Comment: Please explain the reasoning you used to obtain the wrong answer.  That makes it easier for readers of your question to identify any errors you may have made.

Answer (score 1):

On your second approach for at least two pairs of consecutive identical letters,

Yes $\binom{4}{2} \frac{9!}{\left(2!\right)^{2}}$ contains all arrangements of at least two doubles. The problem is that it overcounts them.

For any two given pairs (say $AA, EE$), number of arrangements is $\frac{9!}{(2!)^{2}}$ and this contains all arrangements of triples of $(AA, EE, NN)$ and $(AA, EE, RR)$ - **two** possible triples for the given two pairs. But when your given two pairs are (say $EE, NN$), your arrangements again include triples of $(AA, EE, RR)$.

In short there are only $\binom{4}{3}$ ways of choosing at least $3$ pairs of two identical letters but you are counting them $\binom{4}{2} \times 2 \,$ times. So you need to subtract those extra $8$ times.

Similarly for arrangements of $4$ pairs, there is only one way to choose them. But each of the $\binom{4}{2} = 6 \,$ given two pairs counted them once. Then when we subtracted $8$ times of at least three pairs, we subtracted them $8$ times and so we are net $(-2)$ on arrangements of $4$ pairs. We need to add $3$ arrangements of $4$ pairs to make sure we are counting all $4$ pairs once. Hence our answer should be -

$\displaystyle \binom{4}{2} \frac{9!}{\left(2!\right)^{2}} - 2 \times \binom{4}{3} \frac{8!}{\left(2!\right)^{1}} + 3 \times \binom {4}{4} \frac{7!}{\left(2!\right)^{0}}$

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to get the answer to the second part, having already computed $n(exactly\; 2\;pairs) = 332,640 \;$would be to add $n(exactly\; 3\;pairs) + n(exactly\; 4\;pairs)\\
= \binom 43\left[\frac{8!}{(2!)^1}-\binom 4 4 \cdot\frac{7!}{(2!)^0}\right] + \binom 4 4\cdot \frac{7!}{(2!)^0}$

This would also have maintained the inclusion-exclusion formula used in the same pattern as in the first part.